# Product of More than 2 non-disjoint cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am aware that the product of disjoint cycles is commutative. I am also aware of the “algorithm” for deriving the product of two cycles. But I’m wondering what the rules are for deriving the product of more than 2 non-disjoint cycles, say for instance:

(13)(24)(52)

Should one start with the product (24)(52) and then apply this result to 13, such that (13)(x)?

Or should one start closest to the left and do (13)(24) and then apply 52 to this result, such that (x)(52)?

This much has not been made clear to me...

Comment: [Associativity is a group axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition), so both should give the same result.

Comment: Well now that’s obvious lol. My dumbass somehow abstracted away from groups and was treating permutations as entities in their own right. Thank you